# Python - Can't start a new thread

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running a python 2.7.10 script in my Asus AC68 box. I just call speedtest-cli.py (the speedtest.net py script) from inside a script of mine.

It was working before I rebooted it and now every time I run it I have this error:

```
    Testing download speed.......Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/jffs/scripts/LaMetric/speedtestcli.py", line 268, in producer
    thread.start()
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 745, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
error: can't start new thread
```

Just to be clear, my Asus runs Merlin, an enhanced version of Asuswrt - the firmware used by all recent Asus routers.

The code can be found here: https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli

Comment: Hi Nishant. The code is the speedtest-cli routine that can be found in the net, that's why I didn't copy it. I edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: How about a URL then?

Comment: speedtest-cli can be found here: https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tests on ulimit (thanks Google) and setting

```
ulimit -s  256
```

solved it...

Just anybody can confirm there might be any side effects?